# How to set Sort key as Global secondary index (Another Partition key) in DynamoDB..?

Tags: database-design, primary-key, amazon-dynamodb

I used DynamoDB table with the following fields:

**Primary Partition key** => `user_id`

**Primary Sort key** => `conversation_id`

### Sample table data

`+---------+--------------------+
| user_id | conversation_id    |
+---------+--------------------+
|      10 |    aaaa            | 
|      10 |    bbbb            | 
|      10 |    cccc            |

|      11 |    aaaa            |
|      11 |    bbbb            | 
|      11 |    cccc            |
+---------+--------------------+`

I have two separate queries in dynamodb:

1. To fetch all `conversation_id` by particular `user_id`.
   **If Input 10 => Output => aaaa, bbbb, cccc**
2. How to fetch all `user_id` from particular `conversation_id`?
   **If Input aaaa => Output => 10,11**

I can get the result for 1st query, but how to fetch the 2nd query result.?

Is it a good practice to fetch data by using **Primary Sort key**(`conversation_id`) or

How to assign or create `conversation_id` as **Global secondary index (Another Partition key)**..?

**Note**: I am using PHP (Codeigniter framework)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You need to use `query` to get all the sort keys of a partition key. Please refer the below link.

[Query API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v2/api/class-Aws.DynamoDb.DynamoDbClient.html#_query)

[Query sample code](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/es_es/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/LowLevelPHPQuerying.html)

2) Create the GSI using AWS CLI command.

**Local DynamoDB:-**

You may need to delete the endpoint url and include the appropriate region `--region us-east-1`. Also, please change the table name accordingly.

```
aws dynamodb update-table --table-name Movies --attribute-definitions file://create_gsi_attributes.json --global-secondary-index-updates file://create_gsi.json --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

**create_gsi_attributes.json:-**

Please change the attribute names (and type) to `conversation_id` and `user_id`

```
[{
    "AttributeName": "title",
    "AttributeType": "S"
},
{
    "AttributeName": "yearkey",
    "AttributeType": "N"
}]
```

**create_gsi.json:-**

Please change the key schema attribute names to `conversation_id` and `user_id`

```
[{
    "Create": {
        "IndexName": "Movies_Gsi",
        "KeySchema": [{
            "AttributeName": "title",
            "KeyType": "HASH"
        },
        {
            "AttributeName": "yearkey",
            "KeyType": "RANGE"
        }],
        "Projection": {
            "ProjectionType": "ALL"
        },
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
            "ReadCapacityUnits": 100,
            "WriteCapacityUnits": 100
        }
    }
}]
```

**EDIT:-**

**Command:-**

```
aws dynamodb update-table --table-name message_participants_tbl --attribute-definitions file://create_gsi_attributes_conversation.json --global-secondary-index-updates file://create_gsi_conversation.json --endpoint-url http://localhost:8000
```

**create_gsi_conversation.json:-**

```
[{
    "Create": {
        "IndexName": "message_participants_tbl_gsi",
        "KeySchema": [{
            "AttributeName": "conversation_id",
            "KeyType": "HASH"
        },
        {
            "AttributeName": "user_id",
            "KeyType": "RANGE"
        }],
        "Projection": {
            "ProjectionType": "ALL"
        },
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
            "ReadCapacityUnits": 100,
            "WriteCapacityUnits": 100
        }
    }
}]
```

**create_gsi_attributes_conversation.json:-**

```
[{
    "AttributeName": "user_id",
    "AttributeType": "S"
},
{
    "AttributeName": "conversation_id",
    "AttributeType": "S"
}]
```

Comment: can you use the names `conversation_id` and `user_id` in `create_gsi_attributes.json` and `create_gsi.json`...? I can't able to understand which keyType need to assign for  `conversation_id` and `user_id`.

Comment: What is the data type of user id and conversation id?

Comment: updated the commands and json specific to your table. Please try.